# On around 23-25 December

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

Is it correct to say "on around" for a date? Is it even grammatical correct?

on is as preposition and around acts as adverb

> it will be on around 23-25 December

Can we put adverb after preposition?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to use

> on or around

in the way you are thinking.

However, your sentence would usually be spoken as

> It will be on or around the 23rd, 24th, or 25th of December.

meaning there is some tentativeness in the actual timing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so both are used as prepositions?, can we use adverb after or before prepositions?

Comment: And doesn't it need verb be? "It will be on or around" because from what i've learned that we need verb to be before preposition, such as she is in, she is around, Or it has different rule?

Comment: It will be in (p) here later (adverb)
It will be on (p) around (adverb)
She is from (p) here (adverb)
He is from (p) there (adverb)

Are these grammatical correct?

Comment: "On around" is a bit odd, it sounds like the speaker changed their mind mid-sentence, "on or around", "on or about", otherwise  those are correct, except you're missing a few "."(periods).

Comment: Oh okay thanks and sorry for that, I've been searching the official sites for the rules of adverb after preposition, I can't find one yet. Besides that the "on and around" are both preposition? And it needs verb "to be" right before the preposition? As "it will be on or around".

Comment: You could say "on about the 5th of January" = "on or about" which means "some time around the 5th of January".

Comment: There's a misprint,  you should write "be"

Comment: I'm not saying that was what the question was about, but could it be "It will be on, around 23-25 December"?